# Ada read a string (scanf %s equivalent)

Tags: string, scanf, ada

How can I read a word (skip whitespace and read characters until a whitespace is encountered) similar to `scanf("%s")` in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading a word from standard input.  Written as a function.  (Not tested.)

```ada
function Next_Word return String is
   package Latin_1 renames Ada.Characters.Latin_1;

   subtype Whitespace is Character
     with Static_Predicate => Whitespace in ' ' | Latin_1.HT;

   use all type Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;

   Word : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
   Next : Character;
begin
   Skip_Leading_Space:
   loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Get (Next);
      exit when not (Next in Whitespace);
   end loop Skip_Leading_Space;

   Read_Word:
   loop
      Word := Word & Next;
      Ada.Text_IO.Get (Next);
      exit when Next in Whitespace;
   end loop Read_Word;

   return To_String (Word);
end Next_Word;
```

Answer (score 2):

```ada
Skip_Leading_Space:
loop
   Next := Ada.Text_IO.Get;
   exit when not Next in Whitespace;
end loop Skip_Leading_Space;

Read_Word:
loop
   Word := Word & Next;
   Next := Ada.Text_IO.Get;
   exit when Next in Whitespace;
end loop Read_Word;
```

Comment: Labels are there to make the code clearer and you obviously can make it a procedure using in, in/out and out parameters. You can also make it a function but depending on which Ada revision you use, you may not be able to use all type of parameter passing mode.

Comment: I'm too much of a teacher to give a full solution the first time around. ;-)

Comment: I would absolutely not drop the labels, as they make the source easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You want to scan, so it's best to use what is offered in the Ada standard library for this purpose. One candidate is `Ada.Strings.Fixed.Find_Token`.

```
with Ada.Strings.Fixed, Ada.Strings.Maps.Constants, Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Strings;

procedure Read_Word is
    Text  : constant String    := Get_Line;
    First : Positive;
    Last  : Natural;
    White : Maps.Character_Set := Maps.To_Set (" ");
begin
    Fixed.Find_Token
      (Source => Text,
       Set    => White,
       Test   => outside,
       First  => First,
       Last   => Last);
    Put_Line ("word is: " & Text (First .. Last) & '.');
end Read_Word;
```